# What is the relation between $E[X|A]$ and $E[X|A^c]$, if any, if $(A \cup A^c) = \Omega$?

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation

I'm not sure how we could find one in terms of the other. I know of the rule
$$E[X] = E[X|A]P(A) + E[X|A^c]P(A^c)$$
but even if $E[X], P(A), P(A^c)$ are known, I don't see an immediate way to solve for a value of $E[X|A]$ that is not in terms of $E[X|A^c]$.

For example, take $E[X] = E[X|X < 1]P(X < 1) + E[X|X \geq 1]P(X \geq 1)$ for $X$ being a exponential random variable. I can reduce the equation to terms involving only $E[X|X < 1]$ and $E[X|X \geq 1]$, but am stuck here.

Comment: It's very unclear to me what you are asking. In the first sentence you seem to ask how to find one in terms of the other and then in next you are looking to find a formula for $E[X \mid A]$ that doesn't include $E[X \mid A^{c}]$.

Comment: I apologize - that is definitely unclear. I was trying to express that I wanted to see if I could eliminate one of them from the equation for $E[X]$ and not be left with a trivially true equation (i.e. solve for an actual value of $E[X|X < 1]$.

Comment: So you are given $E[X]$, $P(A)$ and $P(A^{c})$ and you are trying to solve $E[X|A]$ (And the solution should not depend on $E[X|A^{c}]$). Correct?

Comment: that is correct! :)

Comment: Well you need to know something about the dependency of $X$ and $A$. Otherwise it's not possible. For what you know $X$ and $A$ doesn't necessarily have anything to do with each other.

Comment: What about X and A being the event that X < 1?

Comment: In general the answer is that there is no such a formula.

Comment: Otherwise (if you have more information) I would go back to the definition of conditional expectation and use that to calculate it.